# How to find out where is a system command in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, path

(1) Where is the command "mklink"? I searched C:\Windows for it but there is no result.

(2) Is there a generic way like "which" command in Ubuntu to find out the absolute path of a command whose folder may be in %PATH%?

Comment: I feel as if you're trying to use Command Prompt or Powershell commands as if they're a file. This isn't the case in windows. Some commands are only internally used in those two applications. Refer to : https://www.computerhope.com/mklink.htm

Comment: @NatsuKage I need to create link in C#.

Comment: You should always add that kind of info to your question first. ^^; Or else it's hard to answer. Try reading this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/link-to-an-object-or-web-page-with-wf-linklabel-control

Comment: Take a loot at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156754/what-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-mklink-j)

Comment: @KeithMiller I first get to that question then its answer does't work then I try to use mklink then ask it here then I post an answer there...

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 2):

Edit: ignore the below, although I still recommend installing gow you can just use window's where command:

https://ss64.com/nt/where.html

I have `which` in windows, but that is because I installed https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki

GOW's `which` searches the folders in PATH to try to find the script / executable in there (or at least that's what I'm assuming, seems a reasonable assumption)

For example:

```
C:\>which python
C:\Users\Almenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE
```

Or even:

```
C:\>which which
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin\which.EXE
```

Unfortunately mklink was not found in path, so I guess it's some internal windows thing like @Natsu-kage said

```
C:\>which mklink
which: no mklink in (.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files\Redis\;C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Users\almenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\almenon\Google Drive\Dev\dev setup)
```

Comment: Windows has the `where` command. Type `where /?`.

Comment: To access CMD.exe internal commands from outside of CMD.exe use `cmd /c mklink /?`. To know what is an internal command open cmd.exe in notepad, turn wordwrap on, scroll 2/3rd down and they are grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

---

> - Some usage suggestions for the where command **`where.exe`**/
>
>   ---

- For look in all folder/sub-folder in current drive:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ mklink.*
```

---

- For look in all sub-folders in current drive:folder:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "." mklink.*
```

---

- For look in only in current folder (not in sub-folders) in current drive:folder:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe ".:mklink.*"
```

---

- For look in all path in %PATH% variable:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:mklink.*"
```

---

- For save results in a variable by in command line:

  ---

```bat
for /f delims^= %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:mklink.exe"')do set "_path_to_file=%~dpi" && set "_full_path=%~fi"
```

---

- To save the results in a variable on the command line:

  ---

```bat
for /f delims^= %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:mklink.exe"')do set "_path_to_file=%~dpi" && set "_full_path=%~fi"
```

---

- To save the results in a variable in the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file:

  ---

```bat
@echo off & for /f delims^= %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:mklink.exe"')do set "_path_to_file=%%~dpi" && set "_full_path=%%~fi"
```

---

**Obs.:** **`where`** always returns the full path to file.

---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:mshta.exe"

rem ::  results ::

C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe
```

---

---